# Attribute error while installation using Pip

Tags: python, pip

while I am upgrading or installing anything with pip

I am getting this error message:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'packaging'

Please suggest an appropriate solution,  after number of attempts I am still unable to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing a similar problem. It appeared to be because of a stale compiled file (pkg_resources.pyc).
I did

```
import pkg_resources
print pkg_resources.__file__
```

I deleted the compiled file and everything was fine.

resource:
[Github](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2679)

Comment: Thank you Bro, it worked for me :)

Comment: @user3805995 , you are welcome, please accept the answer :)

Comment: I already did Sir :)